# C++ removing a custom digit from a number

Tags: c++, algorithm

can you tell me a way how to remove a digit from a number? For example:

```
Input:
2486 2
```

The second number shows which digit will be removed from the first number.

```
Output:
286
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/VaHLRCKk) is what I've tried:

```
int n, k, p, z = 1;
cin>>n>>k;
p = n;

while(p != 0){
    p = p / 10;
    z = z * 10;
}

switch(k){
    case 1: k = 10; break;
    case 2: k = 100; break;
    case 3: k = 1000; break;
    case 4: k = 10000; break;
    case 5: k = 100000; break;
}

z = z / k;
p = n;
p = p / z;
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. As usual the question is, what have you tried?

Comment: Well, up to now I have tried this:
http://pastebin.com/VaHLRCKk

Comment: Have you tried not typing the key `4`

Comment: No, I haven't tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is a function which solves your problem

```
int removeDecimal( int number, int digitNo )
{
    int result = number;
    int decimal = (int)pow( 10, digitNo ); // caluclate 10.0e<digitNo>

    // int decimal = 1;
    // for ( int i = 0; i < digitNo; i ++ ) decimal *= 10; // alternative to pow( 10, digitNo )

    int div = number / decimal;                      
    if ( div > 0 )                         // test if number is grater than 10.0e<digitNo>
    {
        int rest = number % decimal;       // calcualte right digits
        result = div / 10;                 // calcualte left digits
        result *= 10 * decimal;            // shift left digits to the left
        result += rest;                    // add right digits
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic way is to use the integer division and modulo:

```
 (2486  - (2486 mod 10^3))/10 + 2486 mod 10^2
```

In generic way:

```
 P= pow(10,position)
 (N - (N % 10*P ))/10 + N % P
```

Answer (score 2):

BigOther's response is correct in the first example, but has a mistake in the generic function.

The correct one is (runs in python should you want to test it quickly):

```
A = 10**(position + 1)
B = 10**position

Result = (N - (N % A))/10 + N % B
```

Also notice that the `position` variable starts counting from the right to the left of the number, starting in 0. For instance, in the number 123456, 2's position is 4, which means that running the code above with `N = 123456` and `position = 4` should produce `Result = 13456`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is too obvious.

```
std::string n;
int k;
std::cin >> n >> k;
if (k > 0 && k <= n.size()) n.erase(k - 1, 1);
std::cout << n;
```

To answer the obvious objection: if n is really an `int`, use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to turn it into a string. (And you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to turn it back into an `int`.)

Answer (score 1):

### Hints

- The length of a base 10 number is equal to [image: (log base 10 times Number) + 1]
- To remove the last n digits, you can do [image: Number divided by 10 to the n]
- To get the last n digits of a number, you can do [image]
- To combine 2 numbers into one, ex 100 and 2345 into 1002345, you can do [image: Num1 * (10 ^ (log base 10 of num2 + 1) + Num2]

*It's been a while since I answered this question, I figured it might be better to appear less mysterious with the above hints and show how to use them (without revealing the answer)*

#### You can combine these hints into an algorithm for removing the nth digit, as follows:

- Get the length of your number, call it `D`
- Remove the last `D - n + 1` digits, call this `Prefix`
- Get the last `D - n` digits, call this `Suffix`
- Combine `Prefix` and `Suffix`

Of course handle all the edge cases and such, this is an algorithm not the actual solution.